# Translate .bmp to .jpg in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, jpeg, bmp

I have a Windows C++ program which receives and saves bitmap files (*.bmp).  My customer would like the bitmaps saved as JPEG files instead.  This looks very simple in Visual Studio 2008, but I'm stuck with Visual Studio 6.0 (my employer will upgrade one of these days, but not today).  Is there a simple way to do the conversion in VC++6.0, or do I need an external utility program?  I do not have the resources (i.e. time) to "roll my own".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to use the [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) library. You can either use the command line tools, or integrate the library directly into your program using the [Magick++ API](http://imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php).

Comment: This is what we wound up using.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice would be to use [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533814%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or a library such as [IJG](http://www.ijg.org/)'s. MSDN shows a [GDI+ sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533837%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that demonstrates writing a PNG file. Converting it to produce a JPEG file is just a matter of selecting a different encoder.

Comment: It's even easier than that - use the version of `Image.Save` that takes an ImageFormat parameter. `myimage.Save("filename", ImageFormat::Jpeg);` I completely forgot about GDI+ when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the library from the [Independent JPEG Group](http://www.ijg.org/).